# Destination Net Unreachable - except for major sites

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-networking

So for some reason my internet died a few hours ago on my laptop, and here is some information:

- Laptop connected via Wi-Fi
- Smartphone connected via same Wi-Fi and has no issues at all
- Router reboot did (expectedly) do nothing
- Firewall and virus scanners didn’t change anything
- DHCP is enabled

When pinging a website I get a response from `192.168.1.1` saying “Destination net unreachable” for all 4 packages. When running traceroute, the same thing happens.

But here is the weird thing: I can reach *some* sites, both via browser as well as pinging and traceroute.

Sites that can be pinged and show a successful trace include:

- Google (and all google-related applications like drive and even youtube)
- Facebook
- Wikipedia
- Netflix
- Yahoo

Other major sites that can’t be reached include:

- Twitter
- Spotify
- Steam
- Bing

I have no clue how these sites are related in any way and why some of them work and others don’t. But it’s safe to say that **no** “smaller” site can be reached.

I can ping and trace all websites normally when using my phone’s portable hotspot. So there must be a problem with my laptop and router, but I can think of any conflicts that would make sense.

Comment: Your router is telling you that it does not know how to route packets to the IP addresses that you are pinging. Have you checked with your service provider that they aren't currently experiencing issues?

Comment: @MarkoPolo I'm not really sure about the ISP that I'm using since I'm just a lodger and the router was already installed. There weren't any issues over the past week I've been here and using the wifi though, and since my smartphone wifi still works perfectly fine I think that an ISP related problem can be excluded.

Comment: @JakeGould Yes, I know that. Maybe I didn't clarify it enough, but my smartphone has 0 issues *when connected to the same wifi network as my laptop*. That's why I think that it's not a problem with my ISP but rather my laptop.

Comment: Just a theory, could you try [the ipv6 test](http://ipv6.test-ipv6.com/) site and see if it is an ipv4 issue?

Comment: @TheKB That's interesting, on the first test there were no issues found at all, but for every following test i ran none of the ipv6 sites were reached. The site said that it appears like I'm only using ipv4 connections. I ran the tests over my smartphone since I can't reach the site via my laptop.

Comment: Darn. Since you could reach `2a00:1450:4001:815::200e`, an ipv6 address I was hoping it would work.

Comment: @TheKB May smartphone wifi also died today. I looked up the connection on my laptop once more, and it said that there was ipv6 connectivity but no ipv4 internet access. That also explains why I could ping sites like google: they used an ipv6 adress. My smartphone doesn't support ipv6 at all. So you were indeed correct: It's and ipv4 issue. I still have no idea how to handle it though

Comment: Could you try [this website](http://www.bing.com.sixxs.org/) and see if it works?

Comment: Odd. Good that its fixed though.